# How can i turn an array of arrays from strings to numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm receiving data from a websocket connection on a page, the problem is that i'm receiving a JSON array of arrays of strings while i need an array of arrays of numbers. 
Here is a snapshot of the array:

```
var myArr = 
[["7106.86000000", "0.00255500"],
["7107.34000000", "0.00274200"],
["7107.55000000", "0.11258800"],
["7107.58000000", "0.20000000"],
["7107.67000000", "0.17947000"],
["7107.82000000", "0.08443900"],
["7107.91000000", "0.40000000"],
["7108.00000000", "0.08000000"],
["7108.04000000", "0.00500000"],
["7108.22000000", "0.00200000"],
["7108.31000000", "0.32130200"],
["7108.34000000", "0.32127500"],
]
```

How can i convert those strings to number? Do i need to use my own function or there is already a built in feature to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to achieve this.

```
const newArray = myArr.map( childArr => childArr.map( value => Number( value ) ) )
```

It loops through myArr ( an array of arrays ) and then do the same thing on the children. `.map()` returns a new array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArr = [
  ["7106.86000000", "0.00255500"],
  ["7107.34000000", "0.00274200"],
  ["7107.55000000", "0.11258800"],
  ["7107.58000000", "0.20000000"],
  ["7107.67000000", "0.17947000"],
  ["7107.82000000", "0.08443900"],
  ["7107.91000000", "0.40000000"],
  ["7108.00000000", "0.08000000"],
  ["7108.04000000", "0.00500000"],
  ["7108.22000000", "0.00200000"],
  ["7108.31000000", "0.32130200"],
  ["7108.34000000", "0.32127500"],
]

const numberArr = myArr.map(x => x.map(y => parseFloat(y)))
console.log(numberArr)
```